# Is it possible to convert QGIS 3 measure tool output to polyline?

Tags: qgis, measurements

I am wondering if it is possible to convert the results of the QGIS (3.16.0-Hannover) measure tool to a polyline (or shapefile). I need to make a series of linear measurements and would like to keep a record of the geometry of what I measured. When I try to paste the results of the "Copy All" from the measure tool I get an empty attribute table however the number of blank features shown is the same as the number of measurement segments so, it *feels* like the info is there... somehow....

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any way to export the measurement. Maybe you could edit and create real lines as mesurement lines and calculate the lengths from that layer.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-Sebastien Moreau, I was thinking of that as a "Plan B" and I think it will become plan A... unfortunate though as it seems to be duplication of efforts. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: @Jimbobauer Also there is a style that display the measurement if you want something more visual with this solution (see the QGIS Ressource Sharing plugin > Faunalia Repository > Distance Measurement Styles)

Comment: Thanks @J.R. I will dig a little deeper into that suggestion.